# How can I use and store a list inside a map in dart?

Tags: list, dart, flutter, maps

Aye aye good people,

I need to be able to add and delete elements from a list stored inside a map;

I wrongly assumed that this:

```
 final Map<int,List<int>> _map = Map();
_map[1].add(1);
int _data=_map[1][0];
```

or this:

```
Map<int,List<int>> _map = Map<int,List<int>>();
List _list = List();
_list.add(1);
_map[1]=_list;
int _data=_map[1][0];
```

would work, but doesn't.

So... how does it work?

Thank you in advance,

Francesco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `_map[1]` tries to get the value in the map `_map` for the given key `1`. But at this time `_map` is empty so it returns `null`.

To lazy initialize your map, you can do:

```
final Map<int,List<int>> _map = Map();
_map.putIfAbsent(1, () => <int>[]).add(1);
int _data=_map[1][0];
```